# Strange IncrediBuild error: Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin""=="" was unexpected at this time

Tags: visual-studio-2017, batch-processing, windows-server-2016, incredibuild

In a Jenkins job, I start a batch, which builds my project with these commands:

```
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64    
set PreferredToolArchitecture=x64
BuildConsole "%ROOT%project.sln" /rebuild /cfg="Release|x64" /vsversion="vc141" /log="%ARTIFACTS_DIR%\build_Release_x64.log"
```

Some days ago, this project was compiled by `Visual Studio 2015`, but then we changed and now it should compile with `Visual Studio 2017`.

When the project was compiled with `Visual Studio 2015`, the compilation worked without problems. Since the upgrade to `Visual Studio 2017`, I get this error message in the logs:

```
---------------------------------------------
Build Acceleration Console 9.2.2 (build 2190)
---------------------------------------------
Build Log               2/26/2018 12:21:30 PM
---------------------------------------------

--------------------Build System Warning---------------------------------------
Current logging level may degrade build performance:
    Logging level is set to 'Detailed'
    This may degrade build performance and use more disk space.
    Use the Agent Settings dialog to modify this setting.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin""=="" was unexpected at this time.

1 build system warning(s):
   - Current logging level may degrade build performance
```

On the machine, where the Jenkins job runs, Java is installed in the directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161`.

Did anyone got this message before? Or does anyone have an idea, where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my obvious question but have you tried performing this build without IncrediBuild?
I am asking this since there are similar errors that can happen regardless of IncrediBuild. See for example "Rohit Sinha's" post in the following thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cdap-user/xcK1cMzOrwo

If this is not the case, please contact us at support@incredibuild.com and we will be more than happy to assist you and post here an answer for the benefit of the community.

Disclaimer, I'm an IncrediBuild employee.

Comment: Thank you for your input. When building the project only with VS2017, but without IncrediBuild, the build works without problems.

Comment: I'd highly appreciate if you could contact us directly at support@incredibuild.com so we can get the proper logs from you to understand the problem you experience and post back a response to the community. In your mail to our customer success, please mention this stackoverflow link. Disclaimer, I'm an IncrediBuild employee.